# Can you combine two web app lists

Tags: business-catalyst

In Business Catalyst is it possible to combine two web apps in one list?

For example instead of listing via a web app is it possible to list a category which covers multiple web apps?

Answer (score 1):

No, category filters can only be applied on individual webapp tags.

If you're using Liquid Markup, you could collect the data from each webapp and render the combined results once you have all the lists. Pagination will be complex though.